# Socket.io emit an event with data will disconnect the client with "parse error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I built a Socket.io server which handle connection and event :

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log('New connection');

    socket.on('join', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
   ...
});
```

I'm trying to built a Socker.io client using npm module `socket.io-client`

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io(servHost);

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(`Connected : ${socket.id}`);
        
    socket.emit('join', "Some data");
    socket.emit('otherEvent');

  });

 socket.on('disconnect', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Disconnected");
});
```

Server log :

```
New connection
New connection
...
```

Client log :

```
Connected : IyR4Gr0Gvao16UD6AAAD
parse error
Disconnected
Connected : m8aSe6HI67i6VIBNAAAF
parse error
Disconnected
...
```

Note : If I comment `socket.emit('join', "Some data");` everything works fine, even the `otherEvent` is emited and client can handle the expected event in return (not shown on the code). So I guess the error comes from the data inside `join` event.

`some data` can be string / array or object (I tried everything) I have the same error.

I'm using :

```
"socket.io": "^4.5.2",
"socket.io-client": "^4.5.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `.emit()` expects object as 2nd argument.

I had exactly the same issue, fixed by passing an object:

```
socket.emit('join', {text: "Some data"});
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, unfortunately I already tried to pass an object as the 2nd argument and I had the same error. I still don't understand this issue but I'm almost sure it's raised because I wrap my socket inside a class...

Comment: I was having the same "parse error" issue and the problem was that I was sending an error object, which for some reason made the client to fail to parse it and disconnect as in your example. The solution was to only send the error message over the wire.

Comment: @carpamon what's that mean by "send the error message over the wire"? I am facing exactly the same issue with my React App and I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Bemn ensure you are only sending error.message and not the entire error object through the websocket from the server to the client

Answer (score 0):

I've been stumbling upon on this issue and thinks that it's all because of the socket io.

I've tried :

- matching the socket io version between the client and server (4.6.1 for me)
- tried increasing the maxHttpBufferSize
- Increasing the ping timeout

Basically, i've tried several workaround based on this page : [Socket IO Connectivity Troubleshooting](https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/) but still doesn't work.

Anyway My initial code look like this :

```
const someDataNamespace = io.of('/socket/someData');

someDataNamespace.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  const userId = socket.handshake.query.userId;
  const deviceId = socket.handshake.query.deviceId;
  const organizationId = socket.handshake.query.organizationId;

  const someDatas = await findSomeDatas();

  // create room by userId
  socket.join(userId);
  // emit someDatas
  socket.emit(deviceId, someDatas);
  socket.emit(`${organizationId}-${userId}`, someDatas);

  // listen on event by deviceId
  socket.on(deviceId, async (payload) => {
    const someDatas = await findSomeDatas();
    socket.emit(deviceId, someDatas);
  });

  socket.on(`${organizationId}-${userId}`, async (payload) => {
    const someDatas = await findSomeDatas();
    socket.emit(`${organizationId}-${userId}`, someDatas);
  });

  socket.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('ERROR');
    console.log(error);
  });

  // socket disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    console.log('DISCONNECTED');
    console.log(reason);
    socket.leave(userId);
  });
});
```

Turns out, my problem is all just because the **deviceId is undefined** (client mistakes). So when my code run **socket.emit(deviceId, data)**, that's what makes this code doesn't run properly.

Strangely, it doesn't throw error or anything. It just triggered the **socket.on('disconnect')** event with a reason : **"Transport Close",** and on my client browser console log, the error is **"Parse Error".** This is why for me it seems like the error is coming from the socket.io package itself (turns out, it's not).

Then after i fix it with something like this :

```
   if (deviceId) {
      socket.emit(deviceId, someDatas);
    }
```

It works again.

So, yeah. Maybe in your case, my suggestion you can recheck again, perhaps it's also just because a silly flaw logic on the business logic and has nothing to do with the socket io itself.